# VBA Variant Array - test for empty is not working with integer value of 0

Tags: arrays, excel, variant, is-empty, vba

I've got the following VBA code Extract,

```
Dim ERA_Curves AS Variant
ReDim ERA_Curves(2000,19)

ERA_Curves (350,4) = 0
```

then when I test for

```
ERA_Curves(350,4) <> Empty
```

it returns 'False'

Doesn't it suppose to return True since its got some value in the memory? I want to test if the memory is truly empty, (not assigned with any type value) am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [IsEmpty function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264227.aspx) - used like this:

```
If IsEmpty(ERA_Curves(350, 4)) Then
```

Comparing things to Empty with <, > etc doesn't work but you can assign Empty directly to a Variant if you want to:

```
ERA_Curves(350, 4) = 0

If IsEmpty(ERA_Curves(350, 4)) Then
    MsgBox "empty"
Else
    MsgBox "not empty"
End If

ERA_Curves(350, 4) = Empty

If IsEmpty(ERA_Curves(350, 4)) Then
    MsgBox "empty"
Else
    MsgBox "not empty"
End If
```